# C++ and 3rd party libraries

Tags: c++, libraries

I'm rather new to programming and I need help with libraries. I'm having trouble understanding how to use the libraries. I simply don't know what to do after I download them. They usually have instructions but they're not easy to follow when you're a beginner I suppose.

After they're downloaded I'm faced with a bunch of stuff. Some people say I need to build them but I don't know how to do that. Also there's some "header only libraries" and I don't know what to do with those as well.

Example of what I mean, Boost & portaudio (or any other library), I don't know where to start or what to do.

Can someone help me, please!

Comment: If you are new I say its too early to be worried about this. Concentrate on learning the language first.

Comment: Could you explain which library specifically you're trying to use? If you specified that, maybe we'd be able to give you the proper advice to set you up. Header-only libraries mean that you only need to include the headers in your project.

Comment: @drescherjm That's understandable, I appreciate the suggestion! Thanks :)

Comment: @prkist As of right now, Boost & portaudio. I don't know how to build them or even what to do after I download the zip/gz files. If you could show me somehow how to do that, it would make things a lot easier for me when dealing with let's say a new library :)

Comment: Are you using linux or windows? If you're on linux, you can use apt-get, pacman or other package manager provided by the distribution. If you're on Windows, then http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html is your best friend, as it explains the building process (section 5.2) depending on the compiler you wish to use. Just don't forget to add the compiler to your PATH variable. Once you complete the building process, you need to link the libraries to your project. Concerning this, googling "<my IDE> link boost" would be your best friend.

Comment: Also, I have to agree with @drescherjm when it comes to using external libraries, especially a library as big as boost. Boost is an extremely big library an adding it to your project can be more stress than using one specific feature of it which you want to use. Unless you want to use more features, writing a specific functionality yourself might be more preferable (and would teach you more about how things work) than using an external library.

Comment: @prkist I just want to add Boost.asio to my project, not the whole thing. But yes you and drescherjm are right, I should learn and/or experiment by myself. Adding a library to a project is sometimes necessary and there's not a lot of easy-to-follow guides. But anyways, I really appreciate your answer :) Merry Christmas!

Comment: Well, according to the boost website, Boost.asio does not need to be built in order to be used. In that case, all that you should need to do is putting the asio header file (and .cpp file) into your project. Afterwards, include it as you would your own header file (#include "myheader.h" or #include "/boost/myheader.h" - use the relative path. And if you're using an IDE don't forget to add it to the project itself.) and all should work properly.

Comment: I'm using Qt, so I should copy the boost\asio files to the project directory and that should be it, right? then I can just use my #include just like I would with any other header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see if there’s a distribution for your OS.  On Ubuntu, installing the package through the software manager will install all the files you need for `boost` in the system directory, `/usr/include/`.  **This is by far the simplest solution.**

If this is not an option, you need to build the library from source and install it in a directory of your own choice.  This will usually be your home directory or `/usr/local`.  Typically, the commands for this will be something like:

```
tar xzvf library-x.y.z.tgz
cd library-x.y.z
less README
./configure --help
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --other=options --as=appropriate
make
sudo -u bin -g bin make install
make clean
```

You might then need to add `-I/usr/local/include` and `-L/usr/local/lib` to your compiler command line.

For some libraries, you might need to look up the directories to include with a tool such as `pkg-config`.  If you need to do this, the commands would be:

```
export CFLAGS=$CFLAGS `pkg-config --cflags library`
export LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS `pkg-config --libs library`
```